# Reading External PHP File Using Java

Tags: java, php

I have a quick question.

Currently I have a PHP file named "serverintegration.php" located on my website at www.rune-shadows.com/serverintegration.php .

I have a java that loads and runs the PHP code in the file.

The issue is, it reads the html (the source code) rather than running the PHP.  How do I make it read and run the PHP?  Here is my current code:

**Error:**

```
[12/1/13 10:00 AM]: Web server not responding for query: <br />
```

**ForumIntegration.java**

```
package com.rs2.util;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import com.rs2.model.players.Player;

public class ForumIntegration {

private static final int CRYPTION_ID = 4469139;
private static final String WEBSITE_DOMAIN = "http://www.rune-shadows.com";
private static String OUTPUT_DATA;

public static int ProcessUser(Player player) {
    try {
        String URL = WEBSITE_DOMAIN + "/serverintegration.php?crypt="
                + CRYPTION_ID + "&name="
                + player.getUsername().toLowerCase().replace(" ",  "_")
                + "&pass=" + player.getPassword();
        HttpURLConnection CONNECTION_HANDLE = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(
                URL).openConnection();
        BufferedReader OUTPUT_HANDLE = new BufferedReader(
                new  InputStreamReader(CONNECTION_HANDLE.getInputStream()));

        OUTPUT_DATA = OUTPUT_HANDLE.readLine().trim();
        try {
            // Parse returned internet data.
            int RETURN_CODE = Integer.parseInt(OUTPUT_DATA);
            switch (RETURN_CODE) {

            case -1:
                System.out.println("Wrong CRYPTION_ID.");
                return 10;

            case 1:// Invalid Password.
                return 3;

            case 2:
                int memberGroupId = RETURN_CODE - 2;
                return 2;

            case 0:// no member exists for this username

                return 12;// say they must register on forum

            default:

                return 12;// say they must register on forum

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Web server not responding for query: "
                    + OUTPUT_DATA);
            return 8;// Web server not responding.

        }
    } catch (Exception e2) {
    }

    System.out.println("Web server not responding for query: "
            + OUTPUT_DATA);
    return 11;// website offline
}
}
```

**ServerIntegration.php**

```
<?php
$SQL_HOST = "";
$SQL_USERNAME = "";
$SQL_PASSWORD = "";
$DATABASE_NAME = "";
$CRYPTION_ID = 4469139;

//Check if number is correct.
if($_GET['crypt'] != $CRYPTION_ID) {
echo '-1';
exit;
}

//Declare variables input.
$NAME_INPUT = str_replace("_"," ",$_GET['name']);
$PASS_INPUT = $_GET['pass'];

//Try to connect with specified SQL Server.
if(!@mysql_connect($SQL_HOST, $SQL_USERNAME, $SQL_PASSWORD))
die("Error connecting to SQL Server - " . mysql_error());   

//Select the specified SQL database.
if(!@mysql_select_db($DATABASE_NAME))
die("Error selecting SQL Database - " . mysql_error());

//Query Selected SQL Database.
$SQL_QUERY = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ".$CALL_FROM." =  '".$NAME_INPUT."'");

//Compare login information.
if ($SQL_ROW = mysql_fetch_array($SQL_QUERY)){

if(strcmp($SQL_ROW["username"], $NAME_INPUT) != 0) {//Compare input username to SQL database.

    echo '0'; //Query denied(No user found).

} else {
    $DATABASE_PASSWORD = md5(md5($PASS_INPUT).$SQL_ROW["salt"]);//Generate     correct Password to compare with SQL Database.

    if(strcmp($DATABASE_PASSWORD, $SQL_ROW["password"]) == 0) { //Determine if     password is correct.

        echo '2'; //Successful login.

    } else { 

        echo '1'; //The input Password is incorrect.
    }
}
} else {
echo '0'; //Query denied(Database declined query).
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you want the client to run PHP?

Answer (score 0):

What I gather is that you want the client to render the PHP page locally?

PHP code is interpreted by a web server with a PHP processor module, so unless each client is running some bizarre hybrid web server what your doing isn't going to work.

Comment: I see you removed credentials.  I would change those asap.

Comment: Yeah, adding them was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is that you are getting a mysql error at the back side. For a rough code to check this add the following code 
     String line = null;
     while((line = OUTPUT_HANDLE.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
     }

instead of `OUTPUT_DATA = OUTPUT_HANDLE.readLine().trim();` and what i saw by hittng the URL with empty params was

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/content/23/9717823/html/serverintegration.php</b> on line <b>36</b><br />
0
Web server not responding for query: null
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here is the error message for the PHP found in the original post: http://pastebin.com/67CTvFcc

Comment: well the point i am making here is that you java code just reads the first line of response and you are expecting that line to always return an int. This is wrong in may understanding. Fix your PHP code to handle the errornous conditions. If i send empty parameters with the URL then your PHP code breaks. Add null and empty checks in php code.

Comment: check $SQL_QUERY before passing it to mysql_fetch_array. You'll find that it's false because the query failed.

Comment: and do vote the answer if it helped you get a bit near to solving the problem.